# Configuration Settings of Authcache + File Cache

Tags: 7, caching

I have already file cache module installed and working perfectly except that I've read that it also work with authcache.

So I installed authcache but wondering what is the proper configuration in the settings.php.

In authcache readme file, it gives an example as follows:

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/filecache/filecache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/authcache.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/modules/authcache_builtin/authcache_builtin.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'DrupalFileCache';
```

And my current configuration for file cache module is:

```
$conf['cache_backends'] = array('sites/all/modules/filecache/filecache.inc');
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'DrupalFileCache';
$conf['filecache_directory'] = '/tmp/scfilecache-' . substr(conf_path(), 6);
```

I tried to combine the two configuration as follows without luck:

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/filecache/filecache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/authcache.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/modules/authcache_builtin/authcache_builtin.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_class_cache_page'] = 'DrupalFileCache';
$conf['filecache_directory'] = '/tmp/scfilecache-' . substr(conf_path(), 6);
```

My site returns an error with the config above.

Anyone know what is the correct configuration for authcache + file cache?

Answer (score 1):

After testing for several settings, I came up with the following configuration:

```
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/filecache/filecache.inc';
$conf['cache_default_class'] = 'DrupalFileCache';
$conf['filecache_directory'] = '/var/www/clients/client1/web8/tmp';
$conf['cache_class_cache_authcache_key'] = 'DrupalFileCache';

$conf['authcache_builtin_cache_without_database'] = TRUE;

$conf['page_compression'] = 1;

$conf['page_cache_maximum_age'] = 600;

$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/authcache.cache.inc';
$conf['cache_backends'][] = 'sites/all/modules/authcache/modules/authcache_builtin/authcache_builtin.cache.inc';
```

I am using nginx and just change the `$conf['cache_class_cache_page']` to `$conf['cache_default_class']`. I don't know if I am using the correct config, but this works for me.

And the speed of my server increase significantly when I ab test it.